# Is it possible to detect that site is using reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

If one will reverse proxy a site (copy) - how would one know its reverse proxied and not a real site?

Is there a simple method to detect without content plagiarism tools etc?

Comment: Not all reverse proxies are there to plagiarize sites. Most of the time a reverse proxy is used by the owner of the site. A reverse proxy can perform useful tasks such as removing a port number from the URL, combining several web servers into one, allowing various technologies to work together, or making subdomains into  directories.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to detect if site is using reverse proxy?

Comment: Why do you even need to know that in the first place? Your question is similar to "How to find out how a website is hosted" and for any big one you can have almost no insight on internal architecture of it just by looking from outside. It seems you are kind of only looking at the "plagiarism" case which is mostly orthogonal to using a reverse proxy or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the general case.

It is sometimes possible to deduce that a proxy server is being used by looking at the headers returned with your request, but those will typically be legitimate reverse proxies.

As mentioned by others, proxies are very commonly used to speed up access, provide redundancy and even to merge different back-ends into a single site - all of these are entirely legitimate purposes.

It is entirely practical (common even) for many web servers to act as reverse proxies, or indeed to reverse proxy some content while directly serving other content.  Both Apache and NGINX offer modules to do this.